# how to attach a daterange picker in dropdown select field.?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a select field which carrying 5 dropdown values.7 days,14 days, 30 days and custom. once I click on custom value I want to popup a date-range picker and select particular date from there.? how can I implement that.? is there any way..? please help me

```
 const generateProfileOptions = () => {
    const expirations = [
      {
        id: "1",
        name: "7 days",
        value: 7
      },
      {
        id: "2",
        name: "14 days",
        value: 14
      },
      {
        id: "3",
        name: "30 days",
        value: 30
      },
    
      {
        id: "5",
        name: "custom",
        value: "custom"
      }
    ];
    return expirations.map((option: any) => {
      if (option.id === "5") {
        return (
          <>
            <MenuItem key={option.id} value={option.value}>
              {option.name}
       
            </MenuItem>
            <div style={{ display: "flex", position: "absolute" }}>
              <DateRangePicker dateRange={alarmDateRange} onChange={handleDateRangeChange} timePicker={15} />
            </div>
          </>
        );
      }
      return (
        <MenuItem key={option.id} value={option.value}>
          {option.name}
        </MenuItem>
      );
    });
  };
```

```
<Box sx={{ pb: "1rem" }}>
          

          <Controller
            control={control}
            name="expirations"
            render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
              <>
                {value === "custom" ? <Grid> </Grid> : ""}
                <Select
                  size="small"
                  IconComponent={KeyboardArrowDownIcon}
                  onChange={onChange}
                  value={value}
                  style={{ backgroundColor: "#F7F8FA" }}
                  sx={{ input: { backgroundColor: "#F7F8FA" }, width: "100%" }}
                >
                  {generateProfileOptions()}
                </Select>
              </>
            )}
          />
        </Box>
```

if there any other option exist to implement this feature you can also suggest.?